# Scraping string within double quotes from html using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

From [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uonGZ.png), I just want to scrape the highlighted part only.

I tried this :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re;
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\sandheep\OneDrive\desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.emojimeanings.net/list-smileys-people-whatsapp")
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
for i in soup.find_all("td"):
    print(re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', i))
```

which gave me this error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:\Pycharm\quotes_author_WebScraping.py", line 16, in <module>
print(re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', i))
File "C:\Users\sandheep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\re.py", line 241, in findall
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution!!!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

r = requests.get("https://www.emojimeanings.net/list-smileys-people-whatsapp")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

emojiLink = []

for tableRow in soup.find_all("tr", attrs={"class": "ugc_emoji_tr"}):
    for tabledata in tableRow.findChildren("td"):
        if tabledata.has_attr("id"):
            k = tabledata.text.strip().split('\n')[-1]
            l = k.lstrip()
            emojiDescription.append(l)
print(emojiLink, emojiTitle, emojiDescription)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't really need selenium for this (you can simply used `requests`). Second, it's easier with css selectors:

```
st_st=list(soup.select_one('td[id="U+1F600"]').stripped_strings)
#this assumes you're only looking for the grinning face emoji description
st_st[2]
```

And the output is your expected output.

Comment: Actually I want the description of all emojis while each and every emoji is having a unique ID

Comment: @SandheepKumarPatro Then you should have made in clear in your question.

Comment: I apologize for that, but how to do it?